# Set the Z-Order Index for a Shape Object in Aspose Cells for Java to send the shape behind text

Tags: java, ms-office, office-interop, aspose, aspose-cells

I added a shape object to the existing contents of an Excel worksheet using **Aspose Cells for Java** like so:

```
Shape shape = worksheet.getShapes().addTextEffect(...);
```

Now, I'd like to send the shape behind the text that already existed in the worksheet. I looked up there is the `setZOrderPosition` method on the `Shape` object.

However, it accepts an integer value, and I can't seem to find an enum or a magic number or a sentinel that indicates **Send to Back** like we had the `msoSendToBack` constant in the VSTO/VBA object models.

Besides, their documentation offers no explanation of the values for this method: https://apireference.aspose.com/net/cells/aspose.cells.drawing/shape/properties/zorderposition

So, like all other drawing API, I presume that the Z Order value is relative to the Z-Order of other content on the worksheet.

So, I tried specifying -1 to provide the lowest possible value.

```
shape.setZOrderPosition(-1);
```

That threw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or some such, from which, I infer that the valid values for Z-Order are zero-based.

I provided the value 0, hoping it would be the lowest and would do the job, but appears not.

```
shape.setZOrderPosition(0);
```

The shape still overlays existing text.

How do I set the Z-Order index for the shape object properly so it goes behind the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set wordart shape's transparency to respective value accordingly so the text in those cells should be shown precisely. See the following sample code for your reference:
e.g
Sample code:

........

```
// Get the first default sheet
Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Add Watermark
Shape wordart = sheet.getShapes().addTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.TEXT_EFFECT_1, "CONFIDENTIAL",
        "Arial Black", 50, false, true, 18, 8, 1, 1, 130, 800);

// Get the fill format of the word art
FillFormat wordArtFormat = wordart.getFill();

// Set the color
wordArtFormat.setOneColorGradient(Color.getRed(), 0.2, GradientStyleType.HORIZONTAL, 2);

// Set the transparency
wordArtFormat.setTransparency(0.9);

// Make the line invisible
LineFormat lineFormat = wordart.getLine();
lineFormat.setWeight(0.0);
```

..........

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you. I'd already done that. I was wondering if I could set the Z-Order index on the shape because the native Office Interop assemblies and the native Office COM assemblies, both have the API to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Shape.setZOrderPosition()** method for your needs. It will work if you also change the z-order position of the all or affected shapes.

Please see the following sample code for a reference. I have attached an image which shows the input Excel file used in this code and output Excel file generated by the code.

As you can see inside the image, **Heart is now behind the Text Box**.

**Java**

```
//Load your workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "sample.xlsx");

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);

//Get shape 1 and 2
Shape sh = ws.getShapes().get(0);
Shape sh1 = ws.getShapes().get(1);


//Set the Z-Order Position, first shape to 1 and second shape to 0
sh.setZOrderPosition(1);
sh1.setZOrderPosition(0);

//Save the workbook
wb.save(dirPath + "output.xlsx");
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: The point is: how do I set the Z-Order of the shape such that the shape goes behind the text? This method presumably sets Z-Order indices of objects such as shapes, charts, etc and not of the main text. The other problem with this method is: I have to enumerate all shapes within the worksheet and affect their z-orders if I need to set the z-order of an item.

Comment: This feature needs improvement so that when you set the z-order of an item, you don't have to enumerate all shapes. Please create a post for improvement or new feature request in Aspose.Cells forums.

Comment: That brings me to another interesting point. For the last 15 days, I have been trying to create an account at the Aspose website so I can participate in your online forums but it returns a 500 HTTP status code asking me to try again later. That is why I have been posting these questions here at SO.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. Next time, you try to create an account, please delete all cache or use a totally new profile and I am hopeful, this will resolve your account creation issue. Besides, we will do some improvements and in next releases, setting z-order will be simpler.

Comment: We will add a new method like Shape.ToFrontOrBack() to support it. Hopefully, it will be available in September release.

Comment: Thanks very much. :-)

Comment: I have another request to make for your subsequent releases. A huge pain is that the instance method ShapeCollection.addTextEffect requires the developer to tell it "at which row and which column" the top-left edge of the shape should start.

This presents an extremely arduous problem because the columns and rows in a worksheet may be of uneven widths and heights, some may be hidden, some wrapped to fit text, and some expanded, and yet some locked. With all these variations, it becomes difficult to determine which row and column the next shape that is to be drawn must start. contd..

Comment: contd from the previous comment...

It would have been much simpler if the API just asked us to tell it the X and Y offsets (in pixels) from the top-left edge of the worksheet area where to start drawing the shape. This is a *huge* pain. Could you please make an additional API that asks for pixel coordinates rather than row and column numbers?

Comment: We will look into it and add the method that takes parameters in pixels if possible. Thanks.

Comment: This feature is already available with Shape.setLeftToCorner and Shape.setTopToCorner method. First, you will create shape with 0, 0 parameters then you will use these methods to re-position them in worksheet with pixels.

Comment: Please see this code for your reference. ------// Add Watermark
Shape wordArt = sheet.getShapes().addWordArt(PresetWordArtStyle.WORD_ART_STYLE_1,"Word Art",0,0,0,0,100,100);

wordArt.setLeftToCorner(100);
wordArt.setTopToCorner(100);

Comment: Thank you, Shakeel. Will give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells has implemented the feature (i.e. **Send Shape Front or Back**) in version **17.9** which you can download from Aspose website downloads section. Here is a sample code for your reference.

**Java**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

ShapeCollection shapes = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getShapes(); 

//Add first textbox
sheet.getTextBoxes().add(3, 3, 100, 100);

TextBox tb1 = sheet.getTextBoxes().get(0);
tb1.setText("This is first textbox.");

System.out.println(tb1.getZOrderPosition());

//Add second textbox
sheet.getTextBoxes().add(5, 3, 100, 100);

TextBox tb2 = sheet.getTextBoxes().get(1);
tb2.setText("This is second textbox.");

System.out.println(tb2.getZOrderPosition());

//Add second textbox
sheet.getTextBoxes().add(7, 3, 100, 100);

TextBox tb3 = sheet.getTextBoxes().get(2);
tb3.setText("This is third textbox.");

System.out.println(tb3.getZOrderPosition());

//Bring first textbox to front
tb1.toFrontOrBack(3);

//Send third textbox to back
tb3.toFrontOrBack(-1);

workbook.save(dirPath + "output.xlsx");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose